# How to use magnificPopup in tabbed contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use magnificPopup in tabbed content box that uses jQuery to change content inside of a div here is what i have
Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
  $('#portfolio').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    image: {
      cursor: null,
      titleSrc: 'title'
    },
    gallery: {
      enabled: true,
      preload: [0,1],
      navigateByImgClick: true
        }
  });
});
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })
})
```

Here is the Html that I have :

```
<div class="container">

    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Pools</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Play Area</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Food Area</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
      <ul id="portfolio" class="clearfix">
        <li> <a href="img/70259_Paradise Costa Taurito & Waterpark_13_20110929_041832.gif" title="Brick and Bay Windows"><img src="img/70259_Paradise Costa Taurito & Waterpark_13_20110929_041832.gif" alt="brick and by windows"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/302861500_688.jpg" title="Simple iPad Icons"><img src="img/302861500_688.jpg" alt="old-style ipad icons"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/543604628_432.jpg" title="Mobile Profile"><img src="img/543604628_432.jpg" alt="mobile iphone app profile ui"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/aqua_park_water_slide.jpg" title="New Shoes"><img src="img/aqua_park_water_slide.jpg" alt="new balance shoes"></a></li>
        <li><a href="img/creek58.jpg" title="Rive Radio Icon"><img src="img/creek58.jpg" alt="rive radio icon"></a></li>
        <li> <a href="img/Suan_Siam_Water_Park_1.jpg" title="Blood Pressure app"><img src="img/Suan_Siam_Water_Park_1.jpg" alt="blood pressure app ui"></a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
          <ul id="portfolio" class="clearfix">
        <li> <a href="img/play area 1.jpg" title="Kids Play Area"><img src="img/play area 1.jpg" alt="Kids Play Area"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/Childrens-Play-Area.jpg" title="Childrens Play Area"><img src="img/Childrens-Play-Area.jpg" alt="Childrens Play Area"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/543604628_432.jpg" title="Mobile Profile"><img src="img/543604628_432.jpg" alt="mobile iphone app profile ui"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/aqua_park_water_slide.jpg" title="New Shoes"><img src="img/aqua_park_water_slide.jpg" alt="new balance shoes"></a></li>
        <li><a href="img/creek58.jpg" title="Rive Radio Icon"><img src="img/creek58.jpg" alt="rive radio icon"></a></li>
        <li> <a href="img/Suan_Siam_Water_Park_1.jpg" title="Blood Pressure app"><img src="img/Suan_Siam_Water_Park_1.jpg" alt="blood pressure app ui"></a> </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
         <ul id="portfolio" class="clearfix">
        <li> <a href="img/70259_Paradise Costa Taurito & Waterpark_13_20110929_041832.gif" title="Brick and Bay Windows"><img src="img/70259_Paradise Costa Taurito & Waterpark_13_20110929_041832.gif" alt="brick and by windows"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/302861500_688.jpg" title="Simple iPad Icons"><img src="img/302861500_688.jpg" alt="old-style ipad icons"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/543604628_432.jpg" title="Mobile Profile"><img src="img/543604628_432.jpg" alt="mobile iphone app profile ui"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="img/aqua_park_water_slide.jpg" title="New Shoes"><img src="img/aqua_park_water_slide.jpg" alt="new balance shoes"></a></li>
        <li><a href="img/creek58.jpg" title="Rive Radio Icon"><img src="img/creek58.jpg" alt="rive radio icon"></a></li>
        <li> <a href="img/Suan_Siam_Water_Park_1.jpg" title="Blood Pressure app"><img src="img/Suan_Siam_Water_Park_1.jpg" alt="blood pressure app ui"></a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now What Error I'm Facing Is When I'm Clicking On The Image Of Tab One  magnificPopup Is Working Fine But When I Go To  Second Tab Or Third Tab Its Not Popping Up Its Directly Going To The Image Path Instead Of Showing Popup.
That's What I'm Trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you are reusing the **#portfolio** id and ids should be unique. I modified your code, by adding a **.portfolio**-class and instantiating magnific-popup foreach portfolio-component, so that every inner-tab portfolio will have it's own gallery. See http://jsfiddle.net/9ddbnx7f/ for the changes.

The basic modified html:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
  <ul class="portfolio clearfix"> ... </ul>
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
  <ul class="portfolio clearfix"> ... </ul>
</div>
```

And the updated jquery code:

```
$('.portfolio').each(function(){
    $(this).magnificPopup({...});
});
```